How can I distribute a positive number across negative numbers in excel?
So I am trying to automate a problem, say if you have up to 5 numbers and there is at least one negative number, how can this negative number be minimised by taking from the positive numbers?
Take for instance the array (-27.5, -22, 19.5) by looking at this it's quite easy, we can distribute the 19.5 as 19.5 x 27.5 / (27.5 + 22) = 10.8 and 19.5 x 22 / (27.5 + 22) = 8.7, so we get (-27.5 + 10.8, -22 + 8.7, 19.5 - 19.5) = (-16.7, -13.3, 0).
Take another example (14, -6, 18) should give -2.625, 6, -3.375 to then give (11.375, 0, 14,625).
This is quite straight forward maths as I can identify which cells I need to distribute but am finding it really hard in excel to program.
So say if the row is C14:E19, the C14 cell would be the following:
=IF(C14<0, MIN(SUMIF($C14:$E14,">0"), ABS(C14)) * ABS(C14) / SUMIF($C14:$E14,"<0"), IF(C14>0, -C14 * SUMIF($C14:$E14,"<0") / SUMIF($C14:$E14,">0"), 0))
This firstly gives me the incorrect signs in my test cases but that's a minor thing. The other problem is, take my first case, on the 19.5 it returns 49.5 rather than -19.5 to equalise it to zero and on the second problem -6 returns another -6.
All in all I feel like I'm nearly there but having spent a decent amount of time on this I can't get any further. I'm hoping someone with a fresh head can stop me being stupid....

Try: =IF(A1<0, MIN(SUMIF($A1:$C1,">0"), ABS(A1)) * A1 / SUMIF($A1:$C1,"<0"), IF(A1>0,A1 * SUMIF($A1:$C1,"<0") / MAX(SUMIF($A1:$C1,">0"),ABS(SUMIF($A1:$C1,"<0"))), 0))

You can make it shorter: =LET(α, A1, δ, $A1:$C1, φ, SUMIF(δ,">0"), ε, SUMIF(δ,"<0"), IF(α<0, MIN(φ, ABS(α)) * α / ε, IF(α>0,α * ε / MAX(φ,ABS(ε)), 0)))

Trying to generalise it out a bit, I got:
=LET(range,A2:A4,
sumPos,SUMIF(range,">0"),
sumNeg,SUMIF(range,"<0"),
toAdd,MIN(sumPos,-sumNeg),
IF(range<0,range+toAdd*range/sumNeg,range-range*toAdd/sumPos))


